# Giving index number for nth largest value in list Python

Tags: python, list, indexing

With list `a = [1, 2, 3, 5, 4]` I wish to find the index of the nth largest value. `function(a, 4) = 2` since 2 is the index of the 4th largest value. NOTE: Needs to function for lists containing 500 or more elements and works with looping.

Comment: Please explain what you have tried (with code if possible)

Comment: Can you explain better with a code sample what you are trying to accomplish? Maybe you can solve it differently using any built-in python.

Comment: I am confused by your usage of the word index. The fourth largest value is 2, and its index is 1. Please edit your question such that it makes sense.

Comment: There is no 5th index in this list. If you do a[5] you get an index error

Answer (score 3):

You could index into the result of `sorted(a)` to find the n-th largest value:

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 3, 5, 4]
>>> n = 4
>>> x = sorted(a)[-n]
>>> x
2
```

Then use `a.index()` to find the element's index in the original list (assuming the elements are unique):

```
>>> a.index(x) + 1  # use 1-based indexing
2
```

P.S. If `n` is small, you could also use [`heapq.nlargest()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/heapq.html#heapq.nlargest) to get the n-th largest element:

```
>>> import heapq
>>> heapq.nlargest(n, a)[-1]
2
```

Answer (score 0):

If not using index and max (easiest way) i would just:

```
def funcion (a):
     highest_value = [0, position]
     for x in range(len(a),0,-1):
         value = a.pop()
         if value > highest_value[0]:
             highest_value[0] = value
             highest_value[1] = len(a)-x
      return highest_value
```

This way, you would get the highest value and save it index at the same time, so it should be quite efficient. Using pop is much faster than looking from 0 to end, because access is backward.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're using 1 based indexing.  Assumes values are unique.

```
a.index(sorted(a)[4-1])+1
```

will give you 5.